# Send Push Notification from Web Application using AWS PinPoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-pinpoint

I have a react web application that assigns tickets and a react-native app for user to see their assigned tickets. I want to be able to send a push notification to the user when they are assigned a ticket. I'm looking through PinPoint JavaScript SDK, but having trouble seeing if I can do it. Has anyone been able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this. You use [AWS Amplify Analytics](https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/analytics_guide) to put UserId or any attribute you want to be associated with a user. Then Use [Pinpoint SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Pinpoint.html) to createSegment which attributes target the ones associated with the user. Then [Pinpoint SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Pinpoint.html) to createCampaign for created segment. Hope this helps.